# Time Lookback Calculation

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

I have two columns:

Column A:  Time (seconds from midnight)

Column B:  Value (arbitrary value I've created)

How would I find the average value (column B) at any instance in time(row) looking back over the previous x seconds (column A)?

Lets assume A1 = Seconds after midnight

```
Seconds after midnight    Value
        0                  27
        2                  29
        6                   2
       16                  29
       20                  19
       24                   4
       34                   2
       40                   1
       44                   4
       54                  12
       64                  12
       71                   3
       81                  30
       91                  21
       92                   1
       93                  27
       97                  12
      104                  30
      112                  25
```

Note that time deltas are variable so I can't just look at the last x rows.

A specific question would be:

In a new column (column C) return the average Value of the last 10 seconds of data.

I have no idea how to do this.  Can anyone help?  It'd be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

The output in the first 4 rows of column C would be:

```
Seconds after midnight    Value     Result
        0                  27              No values prior to this one
        2                  29         27   Average(B2) 
        6                   2         28   Average(B2:B3)
       16                  29          2   Average(B4)
```

For each row, I'm taking the current time (16 in the last case)...going back x seconds (10 seconds in this case) and then averaging the values from all the cells in that time range (not including the current value).

My main issue is the time calculation.  I don't know how to calculate it as I roll forward in time and I continue to get more instances as we move forward.  If we go 10 seconds without any new data point then there would be no output since.  If we got one instance in the previous 10 seconds then the output would be that value.  If we got 100 instances in the previous 10 seconds, I need to return the average of that 100 instances.

Again, I'd appreciate any help, hints, links.  This is driving me crazy.

Comment: Could you put the values you're looking for in your question? Like, for the row with 16 seconds after midnight, what average are you expecting? Is it between 29 and 2 (i.e. 6 seconds is included in the 10s before 16s) or only 29?

Comment: Awesome, that's better :)

Comment: Hello Jerry,

I just updated the question.  See the text below "EDIT".

Does that clear this up at all?  My apologies if its still confusing.  I'm struggling at the best way to ask the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following formula in cell C3:

```
=IFERROR(SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,"<"&A3,A:A,">="&A3-10)/COUNTIFS(A:A,"<"&A3,A:A,">="&A3-10),0)
```

`SUMIFS` will get the sum of all values for which the seconds are:

- less than A3 (i.e. less than 2 in this case)
- more or equal to A3-10 (i.e. above -8 in this case)

And this sum is divided by the number of lines found with the same criteria.

If now there is an error (more specifically when the `COUNTIFS` returns 0, you would get `#DIV/0!`) you simply get 0 instead of the error.

Comment: Thanks again Jerry.

I'm currently running into two issues that I'm trying to work around:

Comment: 1)  Max(A3-9,0) always returns a positive number after 9.  If the next data point is at 150 seconds for example...it will return (Max 141,0) which would give the row number of the instance above it...despite it being more than 9 seconds in the past.

Comment: @Scott Ok, so you would want to get `0` in such case? And what is the second issue?

Comment: 2)  Index(B:B, Match(result) )is giving me a row number.  Thus returning to average(rowNUmber:B2) instead of average(cell:B2)

Comment: @Scott Ok, changed the method to use a more basic approach than looking up values. See if that fits the problem better?

Comment: `MATCH` returns a row number. `INDEX` returns an address (cell address, range address).

Comment: You sir, are the man.

Thank you very very VERY much.  It works perfectly.  I learned a lot here already and I'm still chewing through some of it.

So thanks again.

Comment: @Scott Awesome that you got that solved :) If you need clarification on anything, I'll be around.